# Copying a range based on criteria from one sheet to another using vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have created selector in excel which will populate the most appropriate products based on requirements entered, in another worksheet I have a list which has references in column A-C with columns D-J blank.

What I would like to do is when a qty is entered in the selector in range N12:N35 (note there will only be a qty in one row, all other rows would be blank)and I press an add button, columns J-P of the selector in this row to be copied to the other worksheet into the blank cells D-J

I have tried a number of codes, none to any success with various errors. Can anyone please help?

Selector is below with columns I want copied hidden
[image]

I want to paste column J-P of the above to columns D-J below if a qty is entered above. There will only be 1 quantity entered, all other quantities will be blank.

[image]

```
    Sub Add()

    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim foundCell As Range
    Dim mysearch As Integer
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Output")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Selector")
    iRow = Sheets("Output").Range("D2").End(xlUp) + 1

    mysearch = Sheets("Selector").Range("N10").Value

    With Sheets("Selector")
        Set searchRange = Sheets("Selector").Range("N12:N35") ', .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=mysearch, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        ws1.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = foundCell.Offset(0, -4).Value       
'and so on
    End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: what is a "selector"? Please share your sheet layout maybe with a screenshot as it's not very clear what's happening here or what exactly needs to happen. Please share some code you have written, even if it's wrong, as it may help us understand what you are after.

Comment: @JNevill sorry for delay. Added some more details.